# Mysql Procedure Error (execute command denied to user)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Create procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`gnysoftxuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertadmin`(IN  adi  VARCHAR(150))BEGIN Insert Into mekan_tablo (mekan_adi) values (adi); END;
```

Mysql query

```
CALL insertadmin('test');
```

Mysql error:

> execute command denied to user 'gnysoftxuser'@'%'for routine 'xdb.insertadmin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that the MySQL user that you are connecting with does not have the EXECUTE priviledge for the database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html

Comment: A link only answer is of limited help here.

Comment: Link is 404, illustrating the reasoning for expanding link-only answers with a summary of the content.

Answer (score 0):

I can find no documentation on it but it seems that DEFINER user has to have EXECUTE granted even though it is not doing any executing(1).

1. Create user userexecuteonly
2. Grant userexecuteonly EXECUTE
3. Create user userselectonly
4. Grant userselectonlySELECT
5. Create procedure setting DEFINER as userselectonlythat selects data
6. Connect as userexecuteonly
7. Call procedure
8. note error SQL Error (1370): execute command denied to user userselectonly
9. Grant userselectonlyEXECUTE
10. Call procedure
11. Procedure runs and returns data.

(1) There is no reason the procedure would not call another procedure

Which could be a concern if userselectonly is used elsewhere and should not be able to EXECUTE procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant execute privileges.  From the MYSQL command line, logged in as a user with the ability to grant, you would write:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE 'xdb'.'insertadmin' TO 'gnysoftxuser'@'localhost'; 
flush privileges;
```

(in your case localhost would be replaced by %, which is a wildcard and used alone allows any IP address or localhost.  You may want to use a specific IP, localhost or a wildcard for a part such as '192.168.1.%')

After executing those 2 lines, try again.